# How to get files from another server with IIS and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api, network-programming

we have currently a problem covering a file download.
In our setup we have 2 servers. Server-1 is the server that hosts the ASP.NET Core application with ASP.NET Core Identity.
The other server Server-2 contains the files we want to download and is in another domain which we (must) access with a VPN connection.

When I tested it locally it was working really well. Although after publishing it to Server-1 the download stopped working. The paths are correct and if I try pasting the file path into the explorer the PDF is being opened.

I tried it with UNC-path in the application and symlink, shortcut in the filesystem and also as a network drive. Nothing worked, sadly.

I found some related problems in the internet, but most are quite different to ours. In those who are similiar they either didn't work or the problem haven't got solved.

Here a short preview of the download function. Sadly I cannot give you access to our servers to test it.

```
public ActionResult Download(string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                string filePath = _path + filename;                

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    //Logging

                    return View("Close");
                }

                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                return File(fileBytes, "application/force-download", filename);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Logging

                return View("Close");
            }            
        }
```

No exceptions are thrown, it just says the file doesn't exist (but it does).
**Edit:** Because of the check if the file exists an exception wasn't thrown. Here is the exception.

```
System.IO.IOException: Wrong username or password. : '{PATH_TO_FILE}'
   at System.IO.FileStream.ValidateFileHandle(SafeFileHandle fileHandle)
   at System.IO.FileStream.CreateFileOpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
   at Project.Web.Controllers.InvoiceController.Download(String filename) in C:\BuildAgents\1\work\{hash}\Project\Project.Web\Controllers\InvoiceController.cs:line 78
```

Quite interesting to see the last line of the exception, that path is located on our server where TeamCity is running and publishing (again another Server, Server-0)?

Like previously said: the 2 servers are in different domains and Server-1 has access to Server-2 with VPN.

Example: server1domain\webuser -> VPN -> server2domain\user 
Locally this is working well (with debugger)

I read it has to do something with ISS itself. Any ideas why it is (for understanding) and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 2:** 
I implemented this solution and it works fine! https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-access-network-drive-using-c-sharp 
I saw the original solution somewhere on stackoverflow. Will post it, if I find it again.

Comment: You can post your edited content as answer, it will help more forum users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented this solution and it works fine! https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-access-network-drive-using-c-sharp
I saw the original solution somewhere on stackoverflow. I will post it, if I find it again.